# format Telehone in Telrik MVC Grid Client.Template

Tags: string-formatting, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

How can i format Telephone number from xxxxxxxxxx to (xxx) xxx-xxxx

in telerik MVC Grid .client.template.

I tried something like this. which is not working

```
string formatPattern = @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})";

 columns.Bound(e=>e.ID)
 .ClientTemplate(Html.Raw(String.Format("{0:###-###-####}", "<#= Telephone #>") + "<br />"      + Regex.Replace("<#= Fax #>", formatPattern, "($1) $2-$3")).ToString()).Title("Phone / Fax");
```

I tried both ways String.format and Regex.Replace

I also tried `$.telerik.formatString('{0:###-###-####}'<#= telephone =>)`

but no use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this done with the below code.

In Telerik Grid bound the column like this

```
 .ClientTemplate("<#= GetPhoneFaxTemplate(data) #>").Title("Phone / Fax");
```

And the Scripts goes like this

```
function GetPhoneFaxTemplate(data) {
        if (isNumeric(data.Telephone)) {
            var phone = $.telerik.formatString('{0:(###) ###-####}', Number(data.Telephone))
        }
        else {
            phone = data.Telephone;
        }
        if (isNumeric(data.Fax)) {
            var fax = $.telerik.formatString('{0:(###) ###-####}', Number(data.Fax))
        }
        else {
            fax = data.Fax;
        }
        template = phone + "<br />" + fax;
        return template;
    }
    function isNumeric(n) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
    }
```

That's it yureka!